# I cant get on my samsung sm-t387w tablet

Tags: password

I have tried several  passwords that I might have used, but no luck. My tablet is still on and it is asking for a password to turn it off. I even spoke to samsung customer service for an hour and they couldnt fix it.

Comment: get on, get off? what password, google account? do you think password will be gone after reboot?